# Why doesn't the latest Ubuntu 16.04 build support AHCI out of the box?

Tags: disk, 16.04, sata, ahci

So, in reference to this earlier question, which I can't comment on:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/757142/16-04-kernel-support-for-ahci?newreg=b938c2416e6d40c8ac5c3233d16889e5

I am trying to PXE boot Ubuntu 16.04 on new Dell hardware (R220, R230, R330) and I find that drives set to AHCI mode are not detected. Running 'lspci' in a console window (alt-f2) during the install shows the SATA controller, but parted_devices in the same shell doesn't list any disks. I have to go back to IDE mode in order to get things to work.

Does anyone have any ideas about this? I filed this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pxe/+bug/1571762

but who knows if and when that will ever be looked at.